# NoClassDeffoundError in spring android

Tags: android, spring, noclassdeffounderror

Hi guys I am facing problrm as NoClassDeffound: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.
I don't know how it will removed? Please suggest me the solution.

> Error: 05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   org.shopzilla.android.parsing.SearchResult_Json.json_parse(SearchResult_Json.java:10)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   org.shopzilla.android.search.SearchResultActivity$1.onClick(SearchResultActivity.java:26)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   05-16 15:59:03.324:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

code:

```
public void json_parse()
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://catalog.bizrate.com/services/catalog/v1/us/product/2?publisherId=50085&placementId=1&categoryId=1&keyword=iphone+cases&start=0&results=10&sort=relevancy_desc&brandId=&attFilter=&zipCode=90291&biddedOnly=&minRelevancyScore=100&apiKey=58f536aa2fab110bbe0da501150bac1e&format=json";
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "SpringSource");
        System.out.println("Result:"+result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because the RestTemplate is not included in the .apk. I have struggled with this problem for a while myself and found out that i haven't installed the *m2eclipse-android-integration* plugin. After installing the plugin everything worked seamlessly. I am now able to use the "Run as < Android Application" function from within Eclipse/STS.

You may have to create your project again to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add your Spring jar files in libs folder correctly?

- spring-android-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar

If you did try this

Right click on your jar files in libs folder > BuildPath > Exclude Then Right click on your jar files in libs folder > BuildPath > Include your files again

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

> remove jars from build path and rename lib to libs -> done

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-78

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Answer (score 0):

put `.jars` into `/libs` folder, so they to be included in the .apk